# Display each taxonomy term post under a Year and Month heading

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a CPT - 'newsletters' and Taxonomy 'newsletter-groups'

I'm trying to display each post under it's respective term heading with all that terms posts displayed under it showing the Month and Year they were posted (by Postdate).

I thought I had something working , but noticed during testing that if a post had the same 'Month' it would wipe out the year and month for other posts in the same term and also for the terms below it , I have some images to show what I mean and the code I'm using so far.

In the images shown I've appended the post date to the filename for clarity , it would normally be just the filename.

**Not Working if post date month is the same**
[image: Not Working if month the same]

**Working if post date month is different**

[image]

How can I solve this ? do I need to get all the post dates with a separate query and save that ?

Any examples appreciated

```
/*
 * Custom Template: Archive Newsletters
 */


// Remove stuff
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'newsletter_archive_loop' );

function newsletter_archive_loop() {


  //fetch the terms for the newsletter-groups taxonomy
  $terms = get_terms( 'newsletter-groups', array (
    'hide_empty' => 'true',
    'exclude' => 67,  //excluding parent term ID 'school-newsletters' - only want to show term children of 'school-newsletters'
  ));

     
  // run a query for each term
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Define the query
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'newsletters',
    'newsletter-groups' => $term->slug ,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );


    // run the query 

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if( $query->have_posts() ) { 

      echo '<div class="letters">'; 
          
        // output the term name in a heading tag    
        echo'<h4 class="term-heading">' . $term->name . '</h4>'; 

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
          
          // get current month
          $current_month = get_the_date('F');
          // get attachements from custom field
          $attachment_id = get_field('newsletter_upload');
          $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
          $title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );
          // get the filesize
          $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
          $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);

            if( $query->current_post === 0 ) { 
                  echo '<h4 class="date">';
                        the_date( 'F Y' );
                  echo '</h4>';
            
              } else { 

                  $f = $query->current_post - 1;       
                  $old_date =   mysql2date( 'F', $query->posts[$f]->post_date ); 

                  if($current_month != $old_date) {
                    echo '<h4 class="date">';
                          the_date( 'F Y' );;
                    echo '</h4>';
                  }

            } ?>

            <li class="letters-file">
              <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="letters-file-sz">&nbsp;(<?php echo $filesize; ?>)</span>
            </li> 

        <?php } // endwhile have posts

      echo '</div>'; // close letters div
    
      // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
      wp_reset_postdata();  
      
    } // end if query have posts

  } // end for each

} // end function 

genesis(); // call genesis framework
```

**Remove if and else both conditions and try to print only echo ''; the_date( 'F Y' ); echo ''**

it will only show the individual post dates - But not grouped

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I think issue is if($current_month != $old_date) { this condition. because in that case your $current_month will be 'march' and $old will be also 'march'

Comment: would I just delete that  else ?

Comment: can you add an explanation of your logic?

Comment: I grabbed that section of code from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141251/get-wordpress-post-with-each-month

Comment: Remove if and else both conditions and try to print only echo '<h4 class="date">'; the_date( 'F Y' ); echo '</h4>'

Comment: I've edited my post to show the result of doing that - gives the correct date , but not grouped together

Comment: If I switch these around `if( $query->current_post === 0 )` and `$f = $query->current_post - 1; ` change to `if( $query->current_post -1` and `$f = $query->current_post === 0;` it seems to work perfectly !

Comment: Well then cheers... :)

Comment: false alarm , testing shows if I add more than 2 post in the same month date it puts the 3rd post on it's own with the date , so only getting 2 post per month date and then starts over ??

Comment: it's this section - `if( $query->current_post -1 ) { ` if I change that to 2 , it works , but I'm guessing then it will only show 3 grouped , so 4 posts wont work etc etc

Comment: can you show the expected output in your question?

Comment: I've added an image to show the expected output at the end of the post

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push each month in an array and check if the month is already in the array then do not display repeat month.

```
/*
 * Custom Template: Archive Newsletters
 */

// Remove stuff
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'newsletter_archive_loop' );

function newsletter_archive_loop() {

    //fetch the terms for the newsletter-groups taxonomy
    $terms = get_terms( 'newsletter-groups', array (
        'hide_empty' => 'true',
        'exclude' => 67,  //excluding parent term ID 'school-newsletters' - only want to show term children of 'school-newsletters'
    ));
 
    // run a query for each term
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        $dates = array();

        // Define the query
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'newsletters',
            'newsletter-groups' => $term->slug ,
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        );

        // run the query 
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        if( $query->have_posts() ) { 

            echo '<div class="letters">'; 
              
                // output the term name in a heading tag    
                echo'<h4 class="term-heading">' . $term->name . '</h4>'; 

                while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
                  
                    // get current month
                    $current_month = get_the_date('F');
                  
                    // get attachements from custom field
                    $attachment_id = get_field('newsletter_upload');
                    $url             = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                    $title       = get_the_title( $attachment_id );

                    // get the filesize
                    $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
                    $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);

                    if( !in_array(get_the_date( 'F Y' ), $dates ) ){
                        $dates[] = get_the_date( 'F Y' );
                        echo '<h4 class="date">';
                            echo get_the_date( 'F Y' );
                        echo '</h4>';
                    }

                    ?>

                    <li class="letters-file">
                        <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="letters-file-sz">&nbsp;(<?php echo $filesize; ?>)</span>
                    </li> 

                <?php } // endwhile have posts

            echo '</div>'; // close letters div
        
            // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
            wp_reset_postdata();  
      
        } // end if query have posts

    } // end for each

} // end function 

genesis(); // call genesis framework
```

Comment: This shows the month and year for each post in the term , but not grouped together by month and year , just individually.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: dates in archive-newsletters.php on line 57` some terms have no dates showing date at all

Comment: Wait .. my bad this time , didnt copy all the code , missed the `$dates = array();` , working , you are a genius sir ! thank you